# Spring Cloud Kubernetes Configuration Watcher Example

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-kubernetes

Can someone please point me to a simple and complete example using the Spring Cloud Kubernetes Configuration Watcher with a recent version of Spring Boot? I have found a few examples online that use the Config Watcher but they actually reload the properties using the older approach and they don't even realize it (i.e. the properties still get re-loaded without the Config Watcher even running).

Comment: I finally found a working example here:
https://github.com/neo-feng/configwatcherdemo

Comment: I created a project with an example of how to use a watcher and spring-cloud-kubernetes. I hope it'll help https://github.com/energy2522/spring-cloud-k8s-watcher-test